# Unable to contact my own server

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the midst of trying to set up turtlebot and I have encountered this problem.

When I type "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup robot.launch" on my laptop, the following message appears

```
Unable to contact my own server at [http://10.217.252.66:58698/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.
```

I tried pinging myself and it works. Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10238/unable-to-contact-my-own-server/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2011-06-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26176/haooo/) on 2016-03-05**:
How to you check your .bashrc form and how do you find your ROS_IP

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-09-12**:
You can open `.bashrc` by typing `gedit ~/.bashrc` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. I changed the following in my .bashrc from

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.217.252.66:11311 
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.217.252.66
```

to

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://laptop_name:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=laptop_name
```

---

Originally posted by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) with karma: 226 on 2011-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-06-13**:
If you wanted to use numbers, you may have needed ROS_IP instead of ROS_HOSTNAME.

**Comment by [rupendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38736/rupendra/) on 2018-11-28**:
Hi , i am getting the same problem as you said, i am able to get the ping result, but i am unable to run rviz . in that answer laptop_name means user name ?? .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need
$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

---

Originally posted by [clh01s@163.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28082/clh01s@163.com/) with karma: 41 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [muhammedozel](https://answers.ros.org/users/37898/muhammedozel/) on 2018-10-03**:
how can we add this? Actually i am using ubuntu on macbook via parallels and there is no export about localhost or network settings

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it!
You can open .bashrc at first with gedit ~/.bashrc in the terminal and then add the code
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
at the end of this .bashrc file.

---

Originally posted by [yaoyao1900](https://answers.ros.org/users/40358/yaoyao1900/) with karma: 11 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
```

> add these lines in bashrc.

---

Originally posted by [mirchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50124/mirchi/) with karma: 31 on 2019-12-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3